# Magento 2: Need to send email to cc emails

Tags: magento2, order-email, magento2.3.2

I want to send an order confirmation email to the cc emails which are mentioned by the customer on the accounts page. I am able to store the cc emails comma(,) separated. But don't know how to send the email to the cc emails (I don't want to use the core modules for this). Need help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the details here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277620/send-order-mail-multiple-email-adresses/277626#277626

Comment: This solutions is for send the emails to  one specific CC email which are set in admin. I want customer mentioned CC emails in my account page front end

Comment: The solution tells how to do that task. You need overwrite the methods and inject your code to get the customers emails whom you want to cc to.