# Magento 2 How to send order email copy to custom email address with custom module when order placed, by custom observer and events.xml?

Tags: magento2, checkout, email, shipping, sales-order

I have one module where i can set email address in back end. When order placed i want to send that order email copy to my custom email address which is set in backend.

I want to add an observer when order placed and send email copy to my custom email address.

how can i achieve this functionality with custom module?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, so you want to send a new order email to the client and your custom email? Magento has that option, it is a requirement being a custom module?

Comment: I know that Magento has that config in admin. But for example I buy a product and I want to tell a friend that I just bought the product. So I want to write this module

Comment: So you need that to work on the frontend, so the customer insert another email to where the new order email will be sent to along with the one to himself? or just on the backend and only admins can select the email it will be sent to?

Comment: I want the new email added in the checkout page to be sent with the email in sales_email / order / copy_to if any.

Comment: Ok got it, I don't know the best way to do this, I would create a module with the observer sales_order_save_after or some that runs after the order is placed, in that module add the fields you need to checkout, then get the value if inserted with verifications to make it secure then I would load the order then send to that email you collected from the field  with something like $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $this->orderSender->send($order, true);

Comment: Okay I will try the way your answer just came up

Comment: I can't help much creating the field on the frontend and get the value the customer inserted, but I cant tell that in that observer you can get the order using $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();, but I've made a mistake, you can't use that orderSender, I mentioned, it will send it to the customer email again and not the email selected

Comment: oh it looks like this problem is much harder than I imagined

Comment: It's just not a common issue, but, I think should be able to use EmailCopyTo() function or some function on that files, I just don't know how you can do it, I'll try to find something

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277626/86398 This might help, I look a bit fast but I think it might be the way, later I'll check with more time

Comment: thank you for answering my question and i will also try to find out more to find out for my answer soonest

Comment: Hey, I'm checking it, can you try to getSender and then use $sender->sendCopyTo($email) , I don't know if it will work using the sendCopyTo this way but if you can try it. Check vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php might help a bit as example of what magento core use

Comment: Okay let me check  @RuiSilva

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117615/discussion-between-98-boycodobv-and-rui-silva).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> observer and event.xml sales_model_service_quote_submit_before

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_checkoutSession->setEmailCc($quote->getData(CustomFieldsInterface::CHECKOUT_EMAIL_CC));

    }
```

> override plugin Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity

```
public function getEmailCopyTo()
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $currentEmailCc = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $emailCC = $currentEmailCc->getEmailCc();

        $data = $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());

        $data2 = $data.','.$emailCC;

        if (!empty($data) && !empty($emailCC)) {
            return array_map('trim', explode(',', $data2));
        }
        if (empty($data) && !empty($emailCC)){
            return array_map('trim', explode(',', $emailCC));
        }
        if (!empty($data) && empty($emailCC) ){
            return array_map('trim', explode(',', $data));
        }
        if (empty($data) && empty($emailCC)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What event are you using for the observer? I used 'sales_order_place_after' event and it is not working.

Comment: You can see that I use a plugin to do email delivery
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity"
                type="Magepow\CheckoutCustom\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity" />

Comment: https://github.com/ngoducnhuiit/magento2-CheckoutCustom/blob/master/etc/di.xml

Comment: https://github.com/ngoducnhuiit/magento2-CheckoutCustom/blob/master/etc/events.xml

Comment: I use event to create a session checkout and then use magento's built-in function to send it @mechanic

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I override the send() function in "Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" and used '$this->transportBuilder->addBcc($custom_email); ' to send email copy.